# update variable in jQuery after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

My AJAX function is below working successfully until someone `resubmits the AJAX call without a page refresh`. In this case, the AJAX call uses the old value of var amount rather than an updated one.  Therefore, I need to update var amount at the end of my success function but am failing to do so.

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateBidButton', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var amount = ('#curr_bid').val()
  var expire_date = "<?php echo $this->item['expire_date']?>";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "?module=items&controller=index&action=submit",
    dataType: "text",
    data: 'amount=' + amount + '&expire_date=' + expire_date,
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('.auction_box').animate({
        'backgroundColor': '#ffdead'
      }, 400);
    },
    success: function (result) {
      if (result == 'ok') {
        $('.auction_box').animate({
          'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
        }, 500);
        amount = $('#curr_bid').val();
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.auction_box').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        } , 5000);
      }
    }       
  });
});
```

Comment: in the success callback, try `$('#curr_bid').val(amount);` instead of `amount = $('#curr_bid').val();` perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried that. It sets the global variable correctly but because I'm in the ajax call and just refreshing the ajax call, it doesn't set the variable in ajax.

Comment: well, every time you click it SHOULD read the value back `var amount = ('#curr_bid').val()` (assuming there's a missing `$` in that line, by the way - so, I doubt you tried it

Answer (score 0):

in your code amount variable not updated, use

```
   var newValue = ''; // for example get new value from ajax response 
   $('#curr_bid').val(newValue)
```

for updating

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```
$(document).on('click', '#updateBidButton', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var amount = $('#curr_bid').val()
  var expire_date = "<?php echo $this->item['expire_date']?>";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "?module=items&controller=index&action=submit",
    dataType: "text",
    data: 'amount=' + amount + '&expire_date=' + expire_date,
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('.auction_box').animate({
        'backgroundColor': '#ffdead'
      }, 400);
    },
    success: function (result) {
      if (result == 'ok') {
        $('.auction_box').animate({
          'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('.auction_box').css('background-color', '#FFF');
        } , 5000);
      }
    }       
  });
});
```

Missing `$` in 3rd line. No need to reassign the value to `amount` variable in success method.

As you click `amount variable` will get the latest value from `input#curr_bid`.

Hope this will help you.